# Передача аргумента для сборки

Tags: cmake

Пытаюсь понять как при сборке проекта например через командную строку передать параметр.
То есть есть такие хедеры которые идут с исходниками ядра

```
#include <util/sleep.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
```

Так вот, я хочу параметром передать путь по которому эти хедеры и будут искаться и уже будет происходить сборка. Так как сборка может быть с разными версиями ядра.

Например будет такая переменная `set(PATH_TO_CORE)` а потом через `include_directories(${PATH_TO_CORE})` будет передаватся где искать.

Answer (score 0):

Так всё же просто: `cmake -DPATH_TO_CORE="/path/to/core"`
С помощью `-D` создаётся запись в кэш-файле CMake, т.е. это как раз создаёт переменную, которая видна в исполняемом скрипте CMake.

Comment: Не помогает. Если я прям впишу в cmake include_directories(/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-30/include) то все нормально, сразу перестает ругатся что отсутствует файл. А если параметром для сборки -DPATH_TO_CORE="/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-30/include/" но выдает ошибку include_directories(/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-30/include)

Comment: @AlexeyAnanyev, отредактируйте свой вопрос и укажите там всю релевантную информацию. Как cmake запускаете, что у Вас там в `include_directories` и т.д.